# Apache Maven RAR Plugin does not include the project jar in the RAR

Tags: maven

I have the following sources for my Resource Adapter project:

```
test_ra\src\main\java\com\test\app\commons\tracing\impl\aggregator\TraceAggregatorResourceAdapter.java 
test_ra\src\main\rar\META-INF\ra.xml 
test_ra\pom.xml 

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.test.app</groupId>
   <artifactId>test_ra</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>rar</packaging>

   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-rar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>

            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>test</id>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>rar</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                     <includeJar>true</includeJar>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

Maven builds class file test_ra\target\classes\com\test\app\commons\tracing\impl\aggregator\TraceAggregatorResourceAdapter.class
Maven creates rar file test_ra-2.0.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.rar.
But maven does not create jar file test_ra-2.0.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar for this project.
And does not add test_ra-2.0.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar inside test_ra-2.0.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.rar.

What should I change in pom xml to build jar file for this resource adapter and put jar file into rar file?

Comment: Why do you add an execution? Just define the plugin in pluginManagement to define the version... furthermore the configuration `includeJar` is by default `true` (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-rar-plugin/rar-mojo.html)